# Cannot see conversation in omnichannel widget

Tags: profile, servicecloud, omnichannel, livechattranscript, messagingsession

I deployed all our org staff from a sandbox to another, but I am experiencing an issue with our Messaging conversation.

In a nutshell, we can't see the chat conversation when it gets accepted and routed to the agent. Instead, we get this:

[image]

*This chat hasn't started yet. Check back later.*

This only happens for one particular profile called "Front Office", which is correctly configured as all other profiles that have access to this. Other profiles correctly visualize the chat and can interact with it. Funny thing is, it works correctly on the old sandbox where I have deployed from.

I've checked many times all profile permissions and grant, compared the profile in the new sandbox  and the profile in the old one, checked permissions between this Front Office profile and the other profile who correctly visualize the chat, checked queues, omni-channel settings... Nothing is wrong. Everything seems to be fine and I am literally loosing my mind in trying to fix this.

Doing a new deploy is not a good idea: all omni-channels configurations should be done again and we are using change sets, which are a real pain.

Any idea on how to fix this? Is there a particular permission I should check? Again, this only happens for a particular profile, so I guess there must be something there that isn't correctly configured. I've also tried to change profile to a user, and it worked, which confirms that the problem is the Front Office profile.

Any help is much, much appreciated.

Comment: Robruf, please check the Status of the Messaging Session. If the status is "Waiting", you will get this message. Once the Status is updated to "Ended", you can see the conversation. So, once the agent accepts the Messaging Session record and completes it, you should be all good to view the conversation.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue, and I was able to solve it by adding an additional component to the layout page.

Once you're on the page where you accept the messaging, click on 'Setup' located in the top right corner of the page, and then select 'Edit Page.'

In the Lightning App Builder page, search for 'Enhanced Conversation' in the Components section. Drag and drop it into the conversation section.

Remember to save your changes and activate the page.

After completing these steps, the conversation should now appear for the agent.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the Presence Status is enabled in the permission set. Go to the permission set. In the Find Settings search, type "Presence" and make sure that the Presence status for the chat/messaging is available.

Then from the Profile, make sure that the same Presence status is enabled as well.